# How to add Custom Currency option in Magento 2.1.3 Admin

Tags: price, catalog, currency, magento-2.1.3

I have two different stores on my website. For one of the store I need to show product price in "Points" like instead of "**$45.00**" I need to show it as "**45 points**". Like in the image attached.

Note: This change is only for one store. Other store should use USD as the price.

How I can achieve this ??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using a custom currency manager module. In my custom module **etc/di.xml** I gave

```
<preference for="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency" type="My\CurrencyManager\Model\Currency" />
```

My **Model\Currency.php** is:

```
<?php

 namespace My\CurrencyManager\Model;

 class Currency extends \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency
 {
protected $logger;

const NO_SYMBOL     = 1;
const USE_SYMBOL    = 2;
const USE_SHORTNAME = 3;
const USE_NAME      = 4;

const STANDARD = 8;
const RIGHT    = 16;
const LEFT     = 32;

public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\FilterFactory $currencyFilterFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct(
        $context, $registry, $localeFormat, $storeManager, $directoryHelper, $currencyFilterFactory, $localeCurrency,
        $resource, $resourceCollection, $data
    );

    $this->logger = $logger;

}

 public function formatTxt($price, $options = [])
{
    $this->logger->info('++++++++++++++++formatTxt');

    if (!is_numeric($price)) {
        $price = $this->_localeFormat->getNumber($price);
    }

    $price = sprintf("%d", $price);
    $options['name'] = "Reward Points";
    $options['currency'] = "Points";
    $options['symbol'] = "Points";
    $options['display'] = 2;
    $options['position'] = self::RIGHT;
    return $this->toCurrency($price, $options);
}

public function toCurrency($value = null, array $options = array())
{
     $space = ' ';
    if ($value === null) {
        if (is_array($options) && isset($options['value'])) {
            $value = $options['value'];
        } else {
            $value = 0;
        }
    }

    if (is_array($value)) {
        $options += $value;
        if (isset($options['value'])) {
            $value = $options['value'];
        }
    }


     if ($options['position'] !== self::STANDARD) {
        $value = str_replace('¤', '', $value);

        if (iconv_strpos($value, ' ') !== false) {
            $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
            $space = ' ';
        }

        if ($options['position'] == self::LEFT) {
            $value = '¤' . $space . $value;
        } else {
            $value = $value . $space . '¤';
        }
    }

    if (is_numeric($options['display']) === false) {
        $sign = $options['display'];
    }else {
        switch($options['display']) {
            case self::USE_SYMBOL:
                $sign = $options['symbol'].$space;
                break;

            case self::USE_SHORTNAME:
                $sign = $options['currency'].$space;
                break;

            case self::USE_NAME:
                $sign = $options['name'].$space;
                break;

            default:
                $sign = '';
                $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
                break;
        }

    $value = str_replace('¤', $sign, $value);
    return $value;
   }
  }
}
```

This changes helped me to remove the dollar symbol and shows "Points" instead of it. Hope this will helps someone in future.